# mcExam: How can I change the answer output from letters [e.g. (a)] to empty square tick boxes? [\$square$] is not accepted, only [correct] or a number

Tags: mcexam

```
\begin{mcquestions}

\question How much is $2+2$? 

          \begin{mcanswerslist}
          \answer two
          \answer [\&square&]four
          \answer five
          \end{mcanswerslist} 

\end{mcquestions}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: According to the [`mcexam` documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/mcexam), the optional argument to `\answer` is ther to provide points or correct/incorrect values to the answer. See §2.2.2. Also, style options are provided through the `enumitem` package, see §5.3 e.g. `\setlist[setmcanswerslist]{label=\mcanswerlabelfmt{*},noitemsep}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command :

```
\setlist[setmcanswerslist]{label=$\square$}
```